# Как узнать время обновления коллекции?

Tags: mongodb

Как узнать когда последний раз менялась коллекция в mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сначало необходимо включить логирование (по умолчанию оно выключено) `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`. Потом можно сделать запрос: `db.system.profile.find({'command.collection': collectionName},{ts:1})`
где `collectionName` - имя нужной коллекции. Получите список всех обращений к этой коллекции, с указанием времени запроса